# $\frac{1}{n+1} \lt \ln (n+1) - \ln (n) \lt \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: calculus

$$\frac{1}{n+1} \lt \ln (n+1) - \ln (n) \lt \frac{1}{n}$$

I had a go at it and realized that if we note $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ then $F(x) = \ln(x)$ is a primitive of $f$.

Then the double inequality can be written as:
$$f(n+1) \lt \int_n^{n+1} f(x) dx \lt f(n)$$
It says that the area under the graph of $f(x)$ from $x=n$ to $x=n+1$ is always between the $y$ value at $n+1$ and $n$. I think I have seen this double inequality before. Is this true for any function? If not, why is this true in this case?

Comment: You could rewrite the proof of the integral convergence test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Proof)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually a direct application of the *Mean Value theorem*: if the derivative $f'$ of a function $f$ is bounded on an interval $[a,b]$:
 $\;m\le f'(x)\le M\enspace\forall x\in(a,b)$, then 
$$m(b-a)\le f(x)\le M(b-a), \quad x\in[a,b].$$

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is true for (strictly)  decreasing functions.False in general.

Comment: For increasing functions wouldn't the signs be reversed?

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: This is what I wanted to know, for any function $f$ if it is true that the $\int_n^{n+1}f(x)\, dx$ is always between $f(n)$ and $f(n+1)$.

Comment: No. That is not true. @Radu Gabriel